# Can't change theme in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

I can't change the theme of the android studio app, I have installed Material Theme plugin but I can't see the material themes options in the themes dropdown menu (see picture). They used to appear before but now I was checking them and found that they are not appearing anymore. Any idea how to fix this?

[here in the settings I can't find the installed themes in the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WD4F.png)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have themes mixed up?  That's the theme for the actual Android Studio app on your PC, not for the app you write using it.

Comment: what do you mean by "themes mixed up" ? If you mean using some settings of each theme then no and I made sure to uninstall all the themes then reinstalling them but they are not showing in the dropdown menu no matter what I do. May this have to do that I installed android studio using snap and there is a version compatibility issues?

Comment: What I mean is material themes are usually about the app you're writing, not Android Studio yourself.  That wouldn't be controlled by the drop down you showed, which only effects Android Studio itself.  Its possible that there's something out there named "Material  Theme" that actually styles Android Studio itself that I don't know about, which is why I'm asking instead of saying that you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes I am aasking about styling (as skin) of android studio app itself and not the app I am writing using android studio